# Sylvester Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Bonjour,

The equation $\binom{n}{k}=m^l$ has no entire solution for l$\ge$2 and 4$\le$k$\le$n-4.
Suppose that n$\ge$2k (since $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$).

According to the Sylvester theorem, the binomial coefficient (for n$\ge$2k):

\begin{equation}
\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{k!},
\end{equation}

has always a prime factor p greater than k.

I dont't know why this fact implies that $p^l$ divides $n(n-1)...(n-k+1)$.

And I dont't understand why only one of the factors n-i can be a multiple of p.

Can someone please help ?

Comment: What's $l$ in $p^l$? Is it the same as the one in $m^l$? If so, are you assuming in the second part that the equation $\binom{n}{k}=m^l$ *does* have a solution? If not, how is $l$ determined?

Comment: l is an integer greater or equal than 2. It's the same than the one in $m^l$...

Comment: ...Yes, the proof is based on assuming the fact that $\binom{n}{k}=m^l$ has an integer solution for l$\ge$2....

Answer (score 3):

The factors $n-i$ differ by at most $k$, and $k$ is less than $p$, so only one factor can be a multiple of $p$.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the structure of what you're doing; it seems as if you're trying to carry out a proof by contradiction but forgot to announce it. Anyway, based on the comment in which you say that $\binom nk=m^l$ is meant to be assumed (even though you state at the beginning of the question that it can't hold), it follows that each prime factor of $\binom nk$ occurs a multiple of $l$ times, so if by Sylvester's theorem some prime $p\gt k$ divides $\binom nk$, then it must occur at least $l$ times, so $p^l$ divides $\binom nk$, so it must divide the numerator.

Comment: sorry, i didn't mean it clearly.

Comment: To prove that the theorem $\binom{n}{k}=m^l$ has no integer solution for l$\ge$2 is true: we have to assume that is false. So we have to assume that $\binom{n}{k}=m^l$ for some l... and show that it leads to a contradiction.

Comment: @user43414: You don't *have* to assume that it's false. That's just one way of proving it.